# VB.NET interface

Tags: vb.net

I understand the concept of interfaces, however I often find it difficult to find practical examples of how to use them.  I have produced the following code:

```
Public MustInherit Class Deletion2
    Implements DeletionInterface2

    Public MustOverride Function Delete() As String Implements DeletionInterface2.Delete
    Public Function CheckDate() As Boolean Implements DeletionInterface2.CheckDate
        Return True
    End Function
End Class

Public Class System1Delete
    Inherits Deletion2
    Implements DeletionInterface2
    Overrides Function Delete() As String
        Return "System 1 Deleted"
    End Function

End Class

Public Class System2Delete
    Inherits Deletion2
    Implements DeletionInterface2
    Overrides Function Delete() As String
        Return "System 2 Deleted"
    End Function

End Class

Public Interface DeletionInterface2
    Function CheckDate() As Boolean
    Function Delete() As String
End Interface

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Dim IDeletion As DeletionInterface2
        IDeletion = New System1Delete
        IDeletion.CheckDate()
        IDeletion.Delete()
        IDeletion = Nothing

        IDeletion = New System2Delete
        IDeletion.CheckDate()
        IDeletion.Delete()
        IDeletion = Nothing
End Sub
```

In the example above (in page load) I have used a reference to an interface to create an instance of an object, but I do not understand the true benefit of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The benefit of using an abstraction like an interface (or a `MustInherit` class) is that you can treat *any* object that implements the interface the same exact way.

For example, the `System.Data` namespace uses many such abstraction, meaning that implementing the different data providers is easier and since the core is using these abstractions, it doesn't need to change as new implementations are added (things about all the different providers, built in and third party - SQL Server, Oracle, PostGresSQL, MySQL etc...).

Comment: Thanks for that.  I have used the dbConnection abstract class to either connect to an SQL database or an Oracle database at runtime.  My question is more geared towards identifying a methodology to identify classes that can be treated the same.

Comment: @w0051977 - That really didn't come across in the question. The methodology is to look at similarities in behaviour of different classes that have similar responsibilities.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I agree that it did not come across in the question.  I am trying to understand the benefits of interfaces and also a methodology for identifying classes that may be suitable for interfaces.  A lot of authors say that interfaces improve maintainability as changes in the class do not affect the interface, but if you make a change to the return type or signature of a function that is exposed in an interface then the interface has to be changed.

Comment: @w0051977 - That's true. Sometimes interfaces need to change. The benefit is simply that of polymorphism (you can substitute different types). The way to identify classes that should be suitable for interfaces is to see where you would use the different classes identically, barring their actual type.

Comment: That is what I wanted to confirm.  As per my last comment (under your answer) I stated that I used a reference to dbConnection to connect to either a SQL database or an Oracle database at runtime using polymorphism.  Would you always use interfaces where possible?

Comment: Interfaces or abstract (`MustInherit`) classes where polymorphism is important. The [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles include [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) which essentially means that one should code to abstractions, not implementations.

Comment: do you always follow these principles?

Comment: @w0051977 - Usually, though there is always a trade-off in terms of complexity. It is a judgement call.